# PHP mkdir returns 1 but directory does not exist

Tags: php, ubuntu

I am creating directory in php with mkdir it returns true but when i ssh into my server i cannot find directory in specified path.

I have checked in different locations in server.

```
if (!file_exists('/tmp/tmpfileeee')) {

mkdir('/tmp/tmpfileeee',0755);

echo 'created';

}
```

Comment: Do check your project root folder

Comment: did that nothing there

Comment: umm.. please apache error log in your server

Comment: 2nd time my if is not executing so i am hoping there is no error..meaning directory exists

Comment: that means your code is fine. just you need to find the folder. install tree in server and run the command 'tree' in ssh

Answer (score 0):

Does tmp exist where this is executing? Is tmpfileee a file or directory you are trying to create? If tmp does not exist and neither does tmpfileee, I believe you are trying to make 2 directories without a recursive parameter in the call.

My PHP is definitely rusty so maybe someone else can answer better but that was just my initial thoughts looking at it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. tmp/tmpfileee is directory path. this is checking if directory exist or not if (!file_exists('/tmp/tmpfileeee')) if not then it will execute mkdir... so when i ran this first time it creates it but when i execute 2nd time its not entering into this if because directory already exist.

Comment: this is just an assumption not an answer

Answer (score 0):

Just try as that:

```
if (!file_exists('tmp/tmpfileeee') AND !is_dir('tmp/tmpfileeee')) {
    mkdir('tmp/tmpfileeee',0755, true);
    echo 'created';
}
```

`mkdir` creates a folder **not file**.

If you want to create an file:

```
if (!file_exists('tmp/tmpfileeee') AND !is_file('tmp/tmpfileeee')) {
    $fp = fopen('tmp/tmpfileeee', 'w');
    echo 'created';
}
```

or best way:

```
// 1. Check folder and xreate if not exists
if (!file_exists('tmp') AND !is_dir('tmp')) {
    mkdir('tmp',0755, true);
    echo 'folder created';
}
// 2. Check file and create if not exists
if (!file_exists('tmp/tmpfileeee') AND !is_file('tmp/tmpfileeee')) {
    $fp = fopen('tmp/tmpfileeee', 'w');
    echo 'file created';
}
```

**UPDATE**

On some servers, the `tmp` and `temp` folders are restricted.

Check for `open_basedir`.

PHP manual states:

> If the directory specified here is not writable, PHP falls back to the system default temporary directory. If open_basedir is on, then the system default directory must be allowed for an upload to succeed.